# Is Citrix accessible through proxy?

Tags: proxy, citrix

This is first time i am working on citrix so please ignore if i ask something silly.
I have to access Citrix URL of my client "https://Server/Citrix/Xenapp/auth/login.aspx" and port 443.

I am able to access this page and login to it but when i tried to access applications like Internet explorer and File Browser it throws error **"Cannot launch your application. Contact your help desk with followinng info: Cannot connect to the Citrix XenApp Server. Could not find specified Citrix XenApp Server"**

I am under my companies network and accesing it through my companies proxy.
The same URL works very fine when i try it through an open internet connection.

I tried connecting to my IS team but they are not sure of what is going on.
They are not sure if Citrix works fine under proxy so i decided to ask it here.

Could someone clear this to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - Xenapp works with both forward and reverse proxies.  Citrix offers their own reverse proxy system, Netscaler, and there are other vendors that offer reverse proxies that work with Xenapp (Radware, F5).

With that said, addition of proxies complicate the Xenapp deployment.  So an improperly configured deployment could easily break the implementation.  F5 has sample documentation in the form of a [deployment guide](http://www.f5.com/solutions/resources/deployment-guides.html) that illustrates step-by-step configuration on the F5 and Xenapp.  Perhaps your IT team can use that as an example?  Otherwise, it's best to contact the proxy vendor and Citrix for support (get ready for finger-pointing battle).

One quick thought - i'd ask your IT team to verify the Xenapp config to make sure there aren't issues with routing or DNS lookups.  It's fairly common for organizations that use split DNS to not account for the routing differences when accessing services from within the organization, especially if the anticipated use case is for users to access the system from outside the organization.